# $a,b \in R$ a ring. If $a | b$ in $R$ then $bR\subseteq aR$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, divisibility

I was reading some theory on ring theory and came across "ideals". Now somewhere the following was mentioned : $a,b \in R$ a ring. If $a|b\; (in R)$ then $bR\subseteq aR$ , and I have no idea as how the set $bR$ is a subset of $aR$ ? From my thinking $|bR| = |aR| = |R|$ should be true ? Can someone clarify this to me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "To contain is to divide" is the rule for ideals $(a)$ and $(b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b$ divides $a$ implies $b=ca$, $x\in bR, x=br=car=a(cr)$.

Answer (score 1):

To amplify @Tsemo's answer: look at $a = 2$ and $b = 6$ in the ring $\Bbb Z$.
Then $a\Bbb Z$ is all even numbers, and $b\Bbb Z$ is all multiples of $6$, and in fact you can see that the second set is contained in the first. That's because
$$
6 \Bbb Z = 2 (3\Bbb Z) \subset 2 (\Bbb Z).
$$
because $3 \Bbb Z$, the set of multiples of $3$, is a subset of $\Bbb Z$ (all integers).